# Sent Post Request with Body Form Data with fetch()

Tags: javascript, fetch, form-data

I'm trying to Post against an API, It does work when I use Postman and 
attach all my data as "form-data".

When I try it with the js fetch method like this

```
const data = {
  'client_id': 'lorem ipsum',
  'client_secret': 'lorem ipsum',
  'scope': 'lorem ipsum',
  'grant_type': 'lorem ipsum'
};


fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

or like this:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('client_id', 'lorem ipsum');
data.append('client_secret', 'lorem ipsum');
data.append('scope', 'lorem ipsum');
data.append('grant_type', 'lorem ipsum');

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: data
})
```

I get an invalid_request error back, so obviously the API is expecting the data to be something different, can anybody help me out how to transmit the data as formData
in the fetch method as Postman for example does it?

Comment: Use [postman to convert the request to actual code](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/). Then, compare it with yours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error is commonly caused due to mismatch of ***content-type*** between what was supplied by **fetch** method and that expected by the server API.

In the above code, the fetch method is sending content of the type 'aplpication/json'.

If the server is throwing an error for this format, it can be concluded that the server is probably expecting content in a different format.

The valid content-type formats supported are:

- application/json     ***(Not working in the current scenario)***
- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

Therefore, the problem may be solved by changing the 'content-type' header in the **fetch** call from **'application/json'** to one of these other supported types.

**An example of working fetch call:**

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('client_id', 'lorem ipsum');
data.append('client_secret', 'lorem ipsum');
data.append('scope', 'lorem ipsum');
data.append('grant_type', 'lorem ipsum');

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "POST",

  headers: {
   // "Content-Type": "application/json"    --> option 1 (not working)
   // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"   --> option 2
   // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"    --> option 3
   // "Content-Type": "text/plain"    --> option 4
  },

  body: data

})

// Option 5:  Try fetch without any header 
fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  body: data
})
```

**More information:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need to add content type

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```